# LP formulation for minimum edge covering

Tags: linear-programming

Given a simple graph $G(V,E)$, what is the LP formulation for the minimum edge covering? Minimum weight edge covering would also work here. If there are none, then that is an answer too.

I took a class on Theory of Algorithms and Operations Research last semester, and remembered there was an IP formulation for the minimum vertex covering. I couldn't recall if the edge covering formulation is from OpRes/ThAlg. Furthermore, it's near impossible to comb through the lecture material as it was online, and I no longer have access to the online material.

Also, supposing it is from Theory of Algorithms, there might be a chance that it was used to prove that something is NP-complete,  I really couldn't remember.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Approximate LP for vertex cover problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/132714/approximate-lp-for-vertex-cover-problem)

Comment: See if you can answer your own question after reading the other question

Answer (score 1):

In the minimum edge cover problem, you have to find a smallest set of edges that covers all of the vertices. The first thing you want to do is decide which edges you want to include in your edge cover. This can be done by having a variable $x_e\in \{0, 1\}$ for each edge $e$ of the graph. If $x_e=1$, you include the edge $e$ in your graph. If $x_e=0$, you don't. Since you want to minimize the number of edges you pick, you want to minimize the expression $\sum_{e}x_e$. However, you also want to make sure that each vertex gets covered. So, for every vertex $v$, you need a constraint that ensures that $v$ gets covered. You do this by having a constraint that enforces that at least one of the variables associated with the edges incident to $v$ is $1$. This constraint would look like the following:

$$\sum_{\text{$e$ is incident to $v$}}x_e\geq 1$$

This formulation is very general. Whenever you have a problem where you want to cover a set of $B$s using a set of $A$s, you set up $0$-$1$ decision variables for each of the $A$s, and have a constraint for each $B$ ensuring that it does get covered.

As pointed out in the comments, this is actually an integer program formulation since the decision variables are constrained to be integers. Such constraints are not allowed in linear programs. You can replace the constraints $x_e\in \{0, 1\}$ with $0\leq x_e \leq 1$ to get a true linear program. However, solving that linear program might give you a *fractional* edge cover where you're allowed to pick a fractional amount of an edge.

Comment: This is an ILP formulation. That might be worth at least mentioning, since op wants LP.

Comment: @PålGD, thanks! Mentioned that in the edit.